# jQuery Flot how to make an updating chart?

Tags: jquery, charts, live, flot, auto-update

I am busy with the jQuery Flot plugin and I am stuck. How can I update my charts by adding new data?

I hope someone can help me with this, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at example pages, perhaps the source will be of some use?

http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/ajax/index.html and http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/realtime/index.html

Or for all the examples: http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/

Comment: I use a plugin so i can create a table with the numbers and i dont know how i can make that scroll, so maybe you can help me a little?